# npm install is stuck on 'sill idealTree buildDeps'

Tags: node.js, npm

When running `npm install`, the installation goes in an infinite loop. The output remains the same for minutes:

`[..................] - idealTree:PRIVATE.REPOSITORY: sill idealTree buildDeps`

PRIVATE.REPOSITORY is an anonymized name.

As other StackOverflow questions suggest, I tried the following steps:

- delete `node_modules`
- rerun `npm i`: no changes, but the node_modules folder gets (mostly) restored again.
- delete `package-lock.json`
- rerun `npm i`: no changes, but the node_modules folder do not get restored.
- run `npm i --verbose`:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.5.0
2 info using node@v21.7.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\PRIVATE\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v21.7.0\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\repositories-professional\PRIVATE.REPOSITORY\.npmrc Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\PRIVATE\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install
22 verbose argv "install" "--loglevel" "verbose"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\PRIVATE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-08T10_21_23_742Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\PRIVATE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-08T10_21_23_742Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 48ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 12ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 silly fetch manifest @OTHER_PRIVATE/REPOSITORY@1.6.1
39 silly tarball no local data for npm@https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/private/PRIVATE/_packaging/PRIVATE/npm/registry/npm/-/npm-7.24.2.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
```

- update node and npm: no changes

Does anyone else experience the same issue?
What other solutions can I try?

Comment: Can npm actually communicate with the private registry? Do simple command such as `npm search` or `npm view` work?.

Comment: Perhaps some script is running. You can use `--foreground-scripts` to display output from scripts.

Comment: Hi @rveerd thanks for your reply. Unfortunately both `npm search` as `npm view` have no output. `npm i --foreground-scripts` also doesn't show more than the logging above, but one line:`1444 silly tarball no local data for npm@https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/private/PRIVATE/_packaging/PRIVATE/npm/registry/npm/-/npm-7.24.2.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
`

Comment: It seems that npm is trying to fetch the package `npm` from the remote. I am now trying to configurate npm to prefer the local variant of this package.

Comment: This also happens on a different device with a clean install. So the issue is not environment specific.